# How to fix HP motherboard with power failure

Tags: motherboard

I was DIYing some wiring from the motherboard to power an external graphics card when something went wrong. The smell of burning came from the motherboard and now, without any component, when I power it on it beeps 4 times and nothing is displayed on the screen.

According to the HP website it's a PSU failure, but I tried with a replacement PSU and the problem still occurs. It's indeed the motherboard with a power problem.

Do you know of anything I can do to fix it myself ? I examined the motherboard very closely and nothing seems burned.

The computer is an HP EliteDesk 800 G1 SFF with an i7 4770 CPU.

Edit: in fact what happened is that I shorted the +12v wire with the +5v in the SATA power plug in the motherboard (the drives are powered from the motherboard not from the PSU in this setup).

I just discovered that one of the drives that were attached is dead too, but I was able to 'fix' it and extract the data by removing the dead TVS diode from the hdd main board, I will replace that diode to keep the over voltage protection). 
This give me hope I could fix the computer motherboard too, I looked on it but can't see any TVS diode on it.

What kind of damages can a 12v voltage do on a 5v power regulation circuit output? Where should I look?

Of course I ordered a new motherboard (a gigabyte z87) to build a new standard pc with the components I have (CPU, RAM, etc), but I will LOVE to fix this motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

You could try taking it to an electronics expert, although it would be expensive.  As that is a very popular desktop I would just buy another from eBay. I recently paid 40GBP for one without ram or processor. Do this and swap out processor and ram.

Answer (score 0):

Fault finding and repairing a computer motherboard is a job for an electronics and soldering expert. Regardless of what the problem might be. A new MB can be had for cheap, a true expert will cost you €100 every hour, at least.

'DIY' electronics enthusiasts speak about 'letting out the holy smoke' - and the fact that it is very hard to get it back inside.
It leaves through very tiny holes, only occasionally you will see a crater in a component.

*I have been tackling problems like this in less complex "IoT"-type circuitry for a number of years: believe me; you want a new motherboard. May be best to replace the PSU also, so that you won't fry the new MB the first time you attempt to use it.*

Comment: There was an edit added that suggested to TEST the PSU before replacing it; I'd say that even a TESTED PSU may well fry the MB - even a professional PSU producer would avoid using a PSU with uncertain status, even if it was tested OK. A electronics module (or component) may have faults that are not detectable by normal means. To find a latent fault may well require testing beyond what is done in "production" and even the testing done by developers; both of which expect fresh devices/components/modules in their tests. Even certifying labs might miss a thing... these people are NOT all-knowing.

Comment: One more note: The above is especially important as the failure is indicated to be on power feed.